# Get Python characters from Asian text

Tags: python, string, character-encoding, special-characters, southeast-asian-languages

Hello everyone I have a problem
I have this word **"बन्दूक"** that in the counting notepad there are 3 characters but with the following code "`_charaters = list(line)`" there are 6 characters.
How could I get only the 3 characters?

Example:

- ब
- न्दू
- क

Comment: You can use `re.findall(r"\w", line)` to get four characters, not quite what you need, but a step closer.

Comment: That string does actually consist of 6 Unicode code points.  Are you asking how to map from Unicode to what would be considered characters in the chosen language?  That's a hard problem.

Comment: The big problem is that `'न्दू'` maps to *four* Unicode code points: `'\u0928\u094d\u0926\u0942'`.

Comment: Are you looking for [`pyuegc` module](https://pypi.org/project/pyuegc/)? *An implementation of the Unicode algorithm for breaking strings of text (i.e., code point sequences) into extended grapheme clusters (“user-perceived characters”) as specified in [UAX #29, “Unicode Text Segmentation”](https://www.unicode.org/reports/tr29/)*

Comment: @JosefZ don't be shy, post it as an answer.  Particularly if you can demonstrate it with the sample text from the question.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you are looking for [`pyuegc` module](https://pypi.org/project/pyuegc/):

> An implementation of the Unicode algorithm for breaking strings of
> text (i.e., code point sequences) into extended grapheme clusters
> (“*user-perceived characters*”) as specified in [UAX #29, “Unicode
> Text Segmentation”](https://www.unicode.org/reports/tr29/)

**Example** (partially commented, string  **"बन्दूक"** hard-coded):

```
from pyuegc import EGC

def _output(unistr, egc):
    return f"""\
# String: {unistr}
# Length of string: {len(unistr)}
# EGC: {egc}
# Length of EGC: {len(egc)}
"""


unistr = "बन्दूक"
egcs = EGC(unistr)
print(_output(unistr, egcs))

# above code basically copied from https://pypi.org/project/pyuegc/
# below code for deeper insight into the GEC results

import json
print( '\n' + json.dumps(unistr))
print( json.dumps(egcs) + '\n')

import unicodedata
for egc in egcs:
    print(f'\nEGC  {egc}  {json.dumps(egc)}')
    for uch in egc:
        print( f'char {uch}  {json.dumps(uch)}  {unicodedata.name(uch, "???")}')
```

**Result**: `.\SO\78102711.py`

```
# String: बन्दूक
# Length of string: 6
# EGC: ['ब', 'न्दू', 'क']
# Length of EGC: 3


"\u092c\u0928\u094d\u0926\u0942\u0915"
["\u092c", "\u0928\u094d\u0926\u0942", "\u0915"]


EGC  ब  "\u092c"
char ब  "\u092c"  DEVANAGARI LETTER BA

EGC  न्दू  "\u0928\u094d\u0926\u0942"
char न  "\u0928"  DEVANAGARI LETTER NA
char ्  "\u094d"  DEVANAGARI SIGN VIRAMA
char द  "\u0926"  DEVANAGARI LETTER DA
char ू  "\u0942"  DEVANAGARI VOWEL SIGN UU

EGC  क  "\u0915"
char क  "\u0915"  DEVANAGARI LETTER KA
```

Comment: Although pyuegc at times produces odd results. On my system `EGC{"बन्दूक बन्दूक")` would give `['ब', 'न्दू', 'क ब', 'न्दू', 'क']`, i.e. `[('ब', '092C'), ('न्दू', '0928 094D 0926 0942'), ('क ब', '0915 0020 092C'), ('न्दू', '0928 094D 0926 0942'), ('क', '0915')]`

Answer (score 0):

An alternative approach is to use `pyicu` for grapheme segmentation using a break iterator. ICU4C provides grapheme, word and sentence break iterators for a range of locales.

```py
import icu 

def get_boundaries(loc, s):
    bi = icu.BreakIterator.createCharacterInstance(loc)
    bi.setText(s)
    boundaries = [*bi]
    boundaries.insert(0, 0)
    return boundaries

def get_graphemes(loc, text):
    boundary_indices = get_boundaries(loc, text)
    return [text[boundary_indices[i]:boundary_indices[i+1]] for i in range(len(boundary_indices)-1)]

print(get_graphemes(icu.Locale('hi'), "बन्दूक"))
# ['ब', 'न्दू', 'क']
```